# drupal '#process' callback seems not working!

Tags: drupal

here is my hook_elements:

```
function test_elemets() {  
  return array(
    'test_field' => array(  
          '#input' => TRUE,  
          '#process' => array('test_field_process'),
    )
  );
}
```

and process callback:

```
function test_field_process($element, $edit, &$form_state, $complete_form)  
    $element = array();    
    return $element;    
}
```

as you see in process function I used $element=array() to see what happens.But the form is shown as it was before.why?

Comment: What did you expect to happen if you return an empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you expect to happen if you do not implement hook_elements? You function have mistake in name `test_elemets` should be `test_elements`
that is why your element type do not apply so you just call markup type as default one.